# Allow service account access only to a subset of a Firetime Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I need to have some code running on a remote server with access only to a subset of my Firebase Realtime Database.

I figured I was going to be able to create a service account with access to the database, and manage it's more detailed read/write permissions using security rules. This doesn't seem to be the case.

I do not want this service account to have any other access to my Firebase project.

Here is an example of what I thought my security rules would roughly look like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "my_restricted_data": {
      "X": {
        ".read": "auth.my_service_account_id === 'X'",
        ".write": "auth.my_service_account_id === 'X'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looking at the Google Cloud Platform roles and permissions, I can't seem to separate Firebase Realtime Database access out from other important privileges which I do not want to grant to this service.

Is there any way I can make this work?

I am using the ruby firebase https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you're using wraps the Firebase REST API, which in itself can be used to access the database both as an administrative super-user and as a regular authentication user. Unfortunately the two [ways to authenticate](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby#authentication) that the library offers both give administrative access to the database, without a way to specify your own UID. This means that there is no way to limit what your code can do.

I recommend filing a feature request (or a PR) on the repo to add [signing in a regular user through the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth), which will then only be allowed the access that your rules have set for it.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering!

If this SDK had the appropriate options, then would passing additional attributes work? Like this example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges
I am not clear still if this option allows me to limit the service account to access the realtime database with limited read/write permissions, and be prevented from taking any other actions in my project or google cloud accounts.

Or is the best option just to create a standard user account (with username and password)?

Comment: The other thing I didn't mention is that the credentials are being handed to an external party who are building the remote code, hence why I don't want any additional permissions granted. I simply want them to have access to the REST API in order to access only one particular object.

Comment: 1) The link you provide allows Admin SDKs to access Realtime Database as a specific UID, which then allows your security rules to limit what they can do. 2) If you don't trust the code that accesses the database, you should probably not run it with administrative privileges.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I am still a little unsure, though.

Further to your point 2 - Is it even possible to have a service account that only has (limited) access to the realtime database and no acceess to anything else?

Or should I be making this remote code authorise as a regular user instead.

Comment: A service account in principle provides full administrative access to the project. The Realtime Database has a trick that allows the code to limit itself, but any code that uses the service account can also choose to not limit itself. Hence: If you don't trust the code that accesses the database, you should not run it with administrative privileges

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks. I suppose I need to go for the "regular user" approach then.